# Adding tail node on a C list

Tags: c, list, tail

This is my function for add an element at the end of my lista but I can't find a way for fix the loop in the while, can u give me some tips/rules for make this function work?

```
void insCoda(t_lista *l, TipoElemLista elem){
t_lista ultimo;
t_lista temp;


temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
temp->contenuto=elem;
temp->next= NULL;

if(*l==NULL)
{
    *l=temp;
    printf("Dentro if");
}else{

    ultimo=*l;
    while(ultimo->next!=NULL)
    {
        ultimo=ultimo->next;
        ultimo->next=temp;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Assuming `t_lista` is `node *` since you did not provide the definitions of these. You're not iterating to the end of your list before attaching the new element in there.  You're putting it at `ultimo->next->next` every iteration of the loop instead of just looping to get to the end and then placing `temp` at the end.

Comment: Sure, debugger...........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is thoroughly broken:

```
ultimo=*l;
while(ultimo->next!=NULL)
{
    ultimo=ultimo->next;
    ultimo->next=temp;
}
```

On entry, you set `ultimo` to (presumably) the head of the list. Then you advance past it to the next node (`ultimo=ultimo->next`), and immediately set the `next` pointer of that node to your newly allocated node (`ultimo->next=temp`). Except oops, your very next action is to test if the thing you just set is `NULL` or not (and it isn't, unless `malloc` failed). So you process your new node, and set its `next` to itself. And now you're in an infinite loop. If you don't enter the loop (because your head is the only node, so the loop condition fails immediately), you never insert the new node at all (which is nice, because this is saving you from the infinite loop).

A hint: Don't set `next` inside the loop. While I haven't tested, simply moving the set outside the loop should work:

```
ultimo=*l;
while(ultimo->next!=NULL)
{
    ultimo=ultimo->next;
}
ultimo->next=temp;
```

so now you traverse to the final node, then make your new node the final node.